# MacPorts won't switch PHP version

Tags: php, macos, symfony, macports

I'm trying to use MacPorts to switch my PHP versions with the following command : `sudo port select --set php php72` (I'm currently using php71).

Then, when I run the command `sudo port select --list php` it tells me I have the following versions of PHP installed :

```
Available versions for php:
    none
    php71
    php72 (active)
```

Yet, `php -v` tells me that my PHP version in 7.1. So does my Symfony profiler. I really don't understand why it's doing that. What's more it was working fine a few days ago...

Do you guys have any idea how to solve my problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: do a `php -i`, and find out which folder it's running from. It could be you have plain old Mac (or Brew) PHP, as well as port installed version. `which php` will tell you where the php executable is

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did a `which php` and found out that, in my `.zshrc`, I had an alias of php pointing to php71. So I removed that and reloaded my shell as well as my server. Now that run the `php -v` command in the shell or run the symfony server, it does tell me that I'm using version 7.2. So that's done. But I still have a small problem with Symfony. Despite showing me that the server runs on version 7.2 when I run it on the terminal, the profiler still tells me that the site uses version 7.1. Very odd.